# Is there a winget Id for Maven?

Tags: maven, winget

I tried to find a winget ID for Maven but there seems to be none since both

```
winget search -q maven
winget search -q mvn
```

dont deliver a proper result. Is there none or do I overlooked it?

Comment: If there were, it would be in [`manifests/`](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-pkgs/tree/master/manifests) but, as of 2022-03, there's no `maven` in that repo. A previous manifest [was removed](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-pkgs/pull/16791) for using an unofficial download URL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there is none so far, as your research showed.
[git already adapted it](https://git-scm.com/download/win) but [maven did not](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) I think we can safely assume if both the official documentation and winget queries do not lead to a result that there is no formula yet.

Comment: Support for installation of portable/standalone apps https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/182 and
Support installing .zip files https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/140 are both in progress for the 1.3 release of the Windows Package Manager.

Comment: FYI: Links mentioned by @DemitriusNelon should be https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/182 and https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/140 respectively

Comment: The feature for [support for installing portables from a zip](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/pull/2500) has been merged and will be available in [winget 1.4](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases/tag/v1.4.2011-preview). Though it may take some more time until the repository will accept zip files

Comment: I am not quite follwing @kapex, does that change my answer for now?

Comment: @Xanlantos No, your answer is still valid. Right now Winget still can't install Maven (because Maven is packed as a zip file), but Winget will be able to install zip files soon. So Maven _could_ technically be made available with the next Winget release, though I don't know if Maven developers have plans to do so.